# Defining custom method and property blocks on superclass in Matlab

Tags: matlab, class, oop, methods, properties

In Matlab, is it possible to define custom `method` and `property` blocks for a `classdef`?

I.e.

```
classdef Foo < MyCustomSuperclass

   properties (SomeBlockA)
      Var1 = 2
      Var2 = 5
   end

   properties (SomeBlockB)
      Var3 = 2
      Var4 = 5
   end

end
```

My guess is that it would have to be defined on `MyCustomSuperclass`.

Comment: IMO it must be programmed at metaclass level. If you ask for `metaclass(?matlab.unittest.TestCase)` you get a specialized matlab.unittest.meta.class... Unfortunately, such specialization seems completely closed until now...

Comment: `tmp=metaclass(?matlab.unittest.TestCase); tmp.ContainingPackage.ClassList(2)` is matlab.unittest.meta.method, and `tmp=metaclass(?matlab.unittest.TestCase); {tmp.ContainingPackage.ClassList(2).PropertyList(:).Name}`contains the specific method attributes Test, TestMethodSetup, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Some built-in MATLAB classes (e.g. those inheriting from `matlab.unittest.TestCase`) have properties and methods with custom attributes (e.g. `TestParameter` etc), but MathWorks haven't yet given you the ability to create your own custom property or method attributes.

However, depending on why you want to do this, you may be able to abuse a piece of undocumented functionality to achieve what you want.

All class properties and methods (and events as well) have a pair of undocumented attributes `Description` and `DetailedDescription`, which must have a string as their value. So, for example, you can have:

```
classdef myclass
    properties (Description='SomeBlockA')
        var1=1;
    end
    properties (Description='SomeBlockB')
        var2=2;
    end
end
```

The class will function correctly at this point, but will give a red underline in the editor, indicating "Unknown attribute name 'Description'". This has no functional effect, but is annoying; you can suppress it by including the pragma `%#ok<*ATUNK>` (**at**tribute **unk**nown) in your code like this:

```
classdef myclass
%#ok<*ATUNK>
    properties (Description='SomeBlockA')
        var1=1;
    end
    properties (Description='SomeBlockB')
        var2=2;
    end
end
```

If you need to, you can query the `Description` attribute of a property using metaclasses:

```
>> a = ?myclass;
>> a.PropertyList(1).Description
ans =
SomeBlockA
>> a.PropertyList(2).Description
ans =
SomeBlockB
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Sam. Thanks for your reply. It's a neat little trick, but unfortunately I can't use it for my application. Let's hope they open up that functionality later, though. Thanks